# Bloch vector for two qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, information

If I find out the Bloch vector parameters of a mixed density matrix in two qubit space, can one say that there is a pure state at the extremity of this Bloch vector for the case of two qubits?

Comment: What are Bloch vector parameters of a two-qubit mixed density matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My question is for a general Bloch vector of a mixed state, not particular for any particular set of parameters. That is to say that if I get an answer for the above question for any arbitrary mixed state

Comment: You have to clarify your question. Bloch spheres are for single qubits, not two qubits. Also, it helps if you would illustrate it with an example.

Comment: Thanks. I am talking about the Bloch vector representation for two qubits such as the one offered by tensor product of Pauli matrices. See for example : https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0302024.pdf

Comment: A specific question would be : given the representation {r1,r2,... r15} for two qubits, can one always find a pure state at the extremity of this vector if it is a Bloch vector representation ?

Comment: Hi ... I got my answer from another paper... the answer is "we cannot find a pure state at the extremity .... "